# mask one URL with other URL for google apps site with amazon route 53

Tags: amazon-route53

I am facing a problem with URL masking with route 53 dns service.

CASE scene : i have one url abc.xyz.com and want it to get redirected to 123.def.com (it is google apps site) but don't want end user to show 123.def.com but want to show users chosen link like 111.aaa.com

soo whenever user type abc.xyz.com it should redirect to 123.def.com but user should get 111.aaa.com in his browser.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with Route 53, DNS, etc. This is a simple web/HTML question. Browsers show the URL of the site where they got their data, otherwise every hacker would make a site that looks like your favorite site in the hopes of capturing your passwords.

That said, if you can get abc.xyz.com to send a static HTML file, you can use an "iframe" to encase site #2. It will hide the URL, but (depending on the app) may cause usability problems for the users (no bookmarking of pages, etc.)